# Input string was not in a correct format in gridview computation of cells

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, row, computation

I tried to do the computation in this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/661865/How-to-get-total-of-gridview-row-values-asp-net) but it says that input string was not in a correct format. I am computing values of cells in the gridview.
Here is my code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    int tot = 0;
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
          decimal medjtot = (Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[3].Text) * (Convert.ToDecimal(e.Row.Cells[4].Text) / 12)) * Convert.ToDecimal(e.Row.Cells[5].Text);
          Label RowTotal = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label1");
          RowTotal.Text = medjtot.ToString();    
    }
 }
```

Comment: On which line exactly? What are the values of `e.Row.Cells[3].Text`, `e.Row.Cells[4].Text` and `e.Row.Cells[5].Text` exactly?

Comment: those rows are textbox. i will compute the values that i will input there.

Comment: It is impossible to help you without knowing these values. Please provide them..

Comment: e.Row.Cells[3].Text = int, e.Row.Cells[4].Text = decimal, e.Row.Cells[5].Text = decimal

Comment: Not data types, show **data values**. And I don't think these are `int` or `decimal` because `.Text` property will return `string`.

Comment: that is why i converted them to .ToString

Comment: These are the example values: Good For How Many=4000  Consumption=0.48 Allowance=1.02 MRP Qunatity=163.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you do a guard check on your `Text` property for each `Row Cell`. It is possible that the text is `whitespace` or `empty`.

Sample guard check.

```
   if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Row.Cells[5].Text) || 
       string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Row.Cells[3].Text))
          return;
```

Comment: thanks for the response :) is there any other way to compute the last row of the gridview. because my code is not functioning.

Answer (score 0):

Must be on this line :

```
decimal medjtot = (Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[3].Text) * (Convert.ToDecimal(e.Row.Cells[4].Text) / 12)) * Convert.ToDecimal(e.Row.Cells[5].Text);
```

If your cells contain forbiden characters (letter for an int32 for example) the conversion will fail. Check also the culture, the separator for decimal may be a coma or a dot.

Comment: you are correct. the error is that line. but i dont know why it is wrong. those cells are just textbox without any value.

Comment: i mean i haven't inputted anything there. when i run my program, it shows the error.

Comment: So look at the second answer. You cannot use Convert on an empty string

Comment: so will i use the int.Parse?

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to convert empty strings to number which is not possible. Using Int.Parse will not help. Just do as user III says in his answer : "Make sure you do a guard check on your Text property for each Row Cell.". And if one is empty do not convert.

Comment: i tried it. the error is eliminated. thanks for the response Plue! :)